# Pandas groupby: How to group by a specified part of a string

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this (df):

```
| Category | Var1 | Var2 |
| -------- | ---- | ---- |
| Num1    | row  | row  |
| Num1    | row  | row  |
| Num1_    | row  | row  |
| Num1_    | row  | row  |
| Num2    | row  | row  |
| Num2    | row  | row  |
| Num2_    | row  | row  |
| Num2_    | row  | row  |
| Num0_   | row  | row  |
| Num0    | row  | row  |
```

If I use:

```
g = df.groupby('Category')
```

It creates a groupby object g with groups determined by equal Category. In this example
Num1,Num1_, Num2, Num2_ Num0_, and Num0.

I would like to group by only a part of the string.
For example put together Num1 and Num1_ thus ignoring _

Additionally, is there a way to put together Num1 and Num1_ , Num2 and Num2_ but keeping separate Num0_, and Num0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, Here's one way:

1st part:

```
df.groupby(df.Category.str.strip('_'))
```

2nd part:

```
df.groupby(df.Category.str.strip('_').map({'Num1' : 0 , 'Num2' : 0, 'Num0' : 1}))
```

*NOTE:* In the 2nd part you can also replace `NUM2` with `NUM1` or vice-versa.

Comment: Hi, the first part works like a charm. As for the second, I think I did not explain it correctly. I wanted to have 4 groups: (Num1 and Num1_ ) , (Num2 and Num2_ ) , Num0, and Num0_

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should work for the 2nd part:
df.groupby(df.Category.replace({'Num0_':'1'}).str.strip('_'))